# JDBC: How to get current connection?

Tags: jdbc, mybatis

I am trying to create a MyBatis custom FILE type handler for the BLOB of Postgres.

Here is the method I need to implement to fulfill the interface:

```
@Override
public File getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    1.get current connection
    2.get postgreSQL LargeObjectManager from current connection
    3.get oid from ResultSet, so the Larget Object can be found
    4.read the large object and rewrite it into a file
    5.return the file
}
```

However I do not know how to get the current connection in this situation. Is there a way to get connection from ResultSet?

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE:**

PostgreSQL implements blob (large object, not bytea) in a special (nonstandard maybe) way. It saves all blob in pg_largeobject table, and use oid as a "pointer" so you can reference the blob from your real table.

Postgres JDBC driver has separated API to handle blob. More details in the following link:
http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/binary-data.html

Comment: Can't you just get the blob directly from the resultset?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no, PostgreSQL implements blob in a special way. It saves all blob in pg_largeobject table, and use oid as a "pointer" so you can reference the blob from your real table.

Comment: Interesting, I would expect the postgresql JDBC driver to hide that implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Connection connection = rs.getStatement().getConnection();
```

But check this method for get BLOB data directly from `rs`:

```
rs.getBinaryStream("myBlobColumn");
```

Comment: I can not get blob from resultset for Postgres. Please see my update.